# How to sort XElement list in c#

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have a list of `XElement` Objects in c#. Each XElement object has attribute `index`, something like this :

```
<A index="2" .... ></A>
<B index="4" .....></B>
...
..
```

Now i want to sort these elements in ascending order according to its index value. For this i tried :

```
 listOfElement.OrderBy(e => e.Attribute("index").Value);
```

But the elements are not sorted in the list. What i am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Remember, it does not order in-place. Are you using the return value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you're not casting the value to an int. It's harmless in this case, but you might want to do:

```
e => (int)e.Attribute("index")
```

Secondly, the `OrderBy` doesn't do side-effect on the type it operates on, but it returns a new `IEnumerable<T>`. You can overwrite your previous list by writing:

```
 listOfElement = listOfElement.OrderBy(e => (int)e.Attribute("index")).
                     ToList();
```

Alternatively, you can use the `List<T>.Sort(Comparison<XElement>)` method in this way:

```
listOfElement.Sort((e1, e2) => 
            (int)e1.Attribute("index") - (int)e2.Attribute("index"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IEnumerable<XElement> sortShows = from s in listOfElement.Descendants()
                                  orderby (int)s.Attribute("index")
                                  select s;
```

Please try this.